# Azure swapping slot, current processing requests are finished?

Tags: azure, azure-deployment-slots

I have a doubt about swap slot in Azure. Reading https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-site-swaps , It's clear that there are not new request dropped. But what happens with the current processing Requests?

Imagine the following scenario a customer invoke an API method that it takes 30 seconds to complete, in the middle of this request I make a swap slot. What happens with the requests that are processing when swap slots occurs?

Reading the previous link, said that the new staged slot restarts. But Does it waits to complete the processing request? Or is it restarted with out waiting to finish the current requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine the following scenario a customer invoke an API method that it
>   takes 30 seconds to complete, in the middle of this request I make a
>   swap slot. What happens with the requests that are processing when
>   swap slots occurs?

This request is going to Production slot, so it will continue and request will be completed without any interruption.

> Reading the previous link, said that the new staged slot restarts. But
>   Does it waits to complete the processing request? Or is it restarted
>   with out waiting to finish the current requests?

Staging slot restart is not interrupting anything. Because users are using production slot and requests are going to prod slot also. When staging slot is ready and warmed-up azure just swap the slots. So in this case there is a chance that some requests are still on-process state in previous Production slot(now in staging slot) and those will be completed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is true that in-flight requests that initiated in production slot can execute till the very end. It would not make sense for MS from billing perspective either. Once the production slot becomes source it is subject to restart according to MS documentation thus the same timeout applies for in-flight requests as in normal restart. From my observation it is 20-30 seconds after sending restart signal.